# Why am I getting this network error when setting up database mirroring?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, mirroring

I have two servers, one in the Portsmouth, NH datacenter, one in the Kansas City datacenter, same domain.

Trying to set up mirroring. First, does it matter that one server has Windows 2008R2 server and the other has 2012R2 server on it?

Have opened the firewall ports between the two servers, can `telnet` back and forth between the two.

Go through all the mirroring steps and get the generic Microsoft error:

> The server network address "TCP://--------.lm.lmig.com:15025" can not be reached or does not exist. Check the network address name and that the ports for the local and remote endpoints are operational. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1418)

The SQL Server version is 2008 SP3 Standard Edition.

Comment: Are both servers running 2008 SP3? Also, have you checked the both the servers can communicate? Make sure port 1433 is open and that you can ping both servers, both ways.

Comment: Both SQL servers are 2008 R2 SP3, ran a telnet command from both server to the other successfully, the only difference is one server is windows 2012R2 and one is 2008R2.

Comment: Encryption enabled? Have you checked the errorlog ?

Comment: Is it 2008 or 2008 R2? The difference may be negligible in this case but it's important to be clear - they are completely separate releases.

Comment: They are both SQL Server 2008 R2 ,10.50.6000.34